# Javascript module not importing

Tags: javascript, python, html, http

I've been having trouble getting javascript modules to work properly the last week and I've looked around as much as I can but I keep hitting dead ends about how to fix it.

I've got the site running through a python test server which does take into account MIME types:

```
import http.server
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import socketserver

PORT = 8080

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Handler.extensions_map={
        '.manifest': 'text/cache-manifest',
    '.html': 'text/html',
        '.png': 'image/png',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
    '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.js':  'application/x-javascript',
    '.module.js': 'module',
    '': 'application/octet-stream', # Default
    }

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This is the class I'm exporting from terrain_generation.module.js:

```
export class world {
  constructor() {
  }

  static GetCube(){
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x00ff00
    });
    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    return this.cube;
  }

  static HelloWorld(){
    return "Hello world!";
  }
}
```

This is how I'm linking the script to the HTML page:

```
<script type="module" src="./js/terrain_generation.module.js"></script>
```

I've confirmed that the file name used in the source tag is the same as the file name.
This is how I'm importing it and where I'm running into issues:

```
import {world} from "./js/terrain_generation.module.js";
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
The requested module './js/terrain_generation.module.js' does not provide an export named 'world'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Tried using a newer version of python, ran back into the problem of incorrect MIME types.

Comment: Two questions: 1. why are you not just using `python3 -m http.server` and instead trying to roll your own? 2. What do you get if you do `import * as foo from "./js/terrain_generation.module.js"; console.log(foo);`?

Comment: What's your directory structure?

Comment: @JaredSmith I ran into problems with python3 -m http.server not giving the correct MIME types to the browser. Could updating python help with this?
I got in the console:
Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"

Comment: @JoseSolorzano the directory structure is:
css
js
resources
shaders
Assignment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with the javascript MIME types in the python server and found a solution.

I changed the MIME type for .js files to text/javascript and now it works. Since javascript files were being parsed with a MIME type of application/x-javascript I think it could not use the ES6 modules due to a type mismatch.

I don't know why it worked and I will have to research MIME types more before I can figure out what was happening, maybe being a more generic MIME type of javascript helped.

Answer (score -1):

One way to fix this is:
In `terrain_generation.module.js` write `export default class world` instead of `export class world`. And just import it as `import world from "./js/terrain_generation.module.js";`

Comment: This is a guess, and does not answer the question. OP is exporting a named class from a module, it should work as written. That fact that it isn't means that the default export/import will likely fail as well.

Comment: Is default instead of defalut